# PyGObject GLib.MainLoop() and exceptions

Tags: python, glib

I'm using `GLib.MainLoop()` from `PyGObject` in my Python application and have a question.

Is it possible to handle Python exception that raises in `loop.run()`?

For example I'm calling some function using `GLib.MainContext.invoke_full()`:

```py
import traceback, gi
from gi.repository import GLib

try:
    loop = GLib.MainLoop()

    def handler(self):
        print('handler')
        raise Exception('from handler with love')

    loop.get_context().invoke_full(GLib.PRIORITY_DEFAULT, handler, None)
    loop.run()

except Exception:
    print('catched!')
```

I thought that `handler()` should be called somewhere inside `loop.run()` so `raise Exception('from handler with love')` should be catched by `except Exception:`. However, it is not:

```
$ python test.py 
handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in handler
    raise Exception('from handler with love')
Exception: from handler with love
```

It seems that `handler()` called in the middle of nowhere (called from `GLib`'s `C` code?), and not catched by `except Exception:`.

Is it possible to catch all Python exceptions that raises in `GLib.MainLoop.run()`? I have a dozen of handlers called like that so I have to add same `try: ... except OneException: ... exceptAnotherException: ...` wrapper into each handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the exception is not propagated. It is caught and printed. No exception in a Python callback causes the loop to exit.

Comment: We already know that. That's why the question was asked: How to change it?

Comment: Normally an uncaught exception causes the interpreter to quit. As this doesn't happen, there must be something that catches and prints it, so there must be a way to override that something by subclassing or monkey patching.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle these types of errors through `sys.excepthook`

Comment: But normally that handler already causes the interpreter to exit, so why doesn't it do that in signal handlers and how is it blocked? Seems wrong to me, because unhandled exceptions will leave the application in an undefined state.